# Meaning of 'All doubtless nourish the soul, but not all fatten the wallet'

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning

I was going through an [article](http://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21600131-too-many-degrees-are-waste-money-return-higher-education-would-be-much-better) on [The Economist](http://economist.com) about returns of higher education and comparison of returns of various fields of study when I encoutered aforementioned phrase. It was quoted in the context of comparing the returns from liberal arts and humanities to those from engineering degrees.

Can somebody explain what it means? I get the 'fatten the wallet' part, but what is meant by the first part of the phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to the answer above, it is saying that both liberal arts/humanities degrees and engineering degrees are worthwhile from the perspective of 'nourishing the soul.' The meaning of this would be something like ['self-actualization.'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_of_needs)
However, as mentioned by andy, the financial return on degrees ('fatten the wallet') varies. Usually engineers make way more money.

Comment: I found the stance of the article interesting, and not one I altogether agree with. But the OP didn't ask whether I *agreed*!

Comment: Sorry! Where I am from engineers do, in general, make much more money.

Comment: I don't doubt *that* fact. It is the underlying question I see as flawed :-) Not everyone can succeed as an Engineer, nor can everyone succeed in the Arts.

Answer (score 2):

*Fatten [your] wallet* means to have more money.

The writer is putting the view that arts graduates will not earn as much as engineers after graduation.

**Edit**

The writer is not literally referring to the [soul](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul); he means that any degree has the effect of improving people's minds, thinking, and self image.

Comment: Hey @andy256, I get the latter part of the phrase, what is meant by the former?